# Fast way to check if two numbers are mirror (reverse in notation) of eachother in given base

Tags: algorithm, performance, palindrome

I am currently working on a little engine that plays four-in-a-row. In my implementation of a fast evaluation table (one which contains already examined positions to look up when they come up again by analysing, for example, a move order that produces an already examined position), I save the eval together with the best move in said table, under an entry that is unique for each position and corresponds to the representation of the board status (a 6 rows by 7 columns matrix that can contain 0 for the free spot, 1 for the cell occupied by player 1 and -1 for the cell occupied by player 2). This unique id is given by a number that corresponds to a 42 digits base 3 number, where each digit is 0->empty, 1->p1, 2->p2.

Since the id is generated in such a way that a base 3 palyndrome would actually correspond to a mirrored board configuration, i can of course transform the number in the id in an array that contains the base 3 notation, put them in reverse order and check again in the table, but since in engines one should always try to squeeze the maximum performance (and mine is already slow enough :P ), I was wandering if there is any sort of fast trick to help me and, maybe, bring this a step further and do this kind of check for any possible base, given that I am thinking of extending the game to more players.

So if any of you have even just an idea, it is well accepted!

PS: if you want me to post some code I can, but I really don't see the necessity of that, given we are talking algorithms.

super-PS: please forgive my bad English! :D

Comment: A naive question: for the id, why not using a pair of coordinates, one coordinate (another pair) for each player? 42^2 versus 3^42 ....

Comment: @Damien: I think the id encodes the whole board, not just the recent moves. ("The cell occupied" should probably be "the cell is occuiped" or "a cell that is occupied". I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) is the game in question.)

Comment: well, now that I think of it, it surely is way more effective, at least on the memory side. The only problem that I think it may arise is that with this method I wouldn't know what entries to look for the symmetrical position check (?)

Comment: @MOehm yes, the id that i was using encodes the whole board

Comment: @MOehm Yes, you must be right!

Comment: If the game is a standard two-player Connect Four, then each column can be encoded as a single byte, resulting in a 56-bit encoding (which is more compact than the 67-bit base-3 encoding). And mirroring the board only requires 3 byte swaps. Each byte is encoded as a sequence of 1 bits followed by a 0 bit, followed by 0/1 bits that indicate ownership. So for example, an empty column is encoded as 11111110, a full column is encoded as 10xxxxxx, and a column with 3 discs is encoded as 11110xxx (where `x` is 0 for playerA, and 1 for playerB).

Comment: @user3386109 This is actually BRILLIANT, even though it is applicable just to the 2 player variant, it is extremely fast, plus the fact that I can use bytes is fantastic (both from a memory management and a speed of swap). For now I will implement your solution using 64 bits integers, but maybe down the line I could compress 8 boards at a time into 7 64bit integers and it wouldn't even be difficult, given it would be just bit manipulation at that point. I will leave the thread open still just to se if there's any solution to the original palindrome problem, just in case :P.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds good. Best of luck with the project :)